# apply custom function to columns in R

Tags: r, apply

Here is my code, I expect it to insert zero into second place of every column, but it does not work.

```
insert_zero <- function(smpl_vec){
  return(smpl_vec[2]<-0)
}

my_df = data.frame('col_1'= c(1,2,3), 'col_2'= c(2,3,4))
apply(my_df, 2, insert_zero)
```

How can I fix  it?

P.S. This is just simplified example. Actual function is more complicated.

Comment: The answers so far are all sort of dancing around two issues: (1) your `return` statement was wrong, and (2) you shouldn't be using `apply` for this. If you want to operate on columns of a data frame, use `lapply`, although the idioms are a bit odd: `my_df[] <- lapply(my_df,insert_zero)`.

Comment: @joran, thank you! What are benefits of using `lapply` vs. `apply`?

Comment: Using `apply` on data frames is a very common source of bugs. If you read `?apply` carefully, you'll see that the first thing it does is convert your data frame to a matrix. If you have columns of mixed types, this will often end up converting everything to characters. `apply` is intended to work on matrices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return(smpl_vec[2]<-0)` doesn't return the modified vector

```
insert_zero <- function(smpl_vec){
  smpl_vec[2]<-0
  return(smpl_vec)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only returning the 2nd value in each column with your current function. This change will make the second value 0 but still return each column in their entirety:

```
insert_zero <- function(smpl_vec){
  smpl_vec[2] <- 0
  return(smpl_vec)
}

my_df = data.frame('col_1'= c(1,2,3), 'col_2'= c(2,3,4))
apply(my_df, 2, insert_zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the entire second row with zeros:

```
my_df[2, ] <- 0
```

Be aware that `my_df` is a data.frame with rows and columns

Comment: Thank you, but it meant to be a simple illustration for more complex function.

Comment: In what way is it more complicated? You would have to be a bit more specific, so that we don't have to guess what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for asking this question. While looking for a solution, I did learn something new. While assigning a new value to cell

```
 1)  use '<' twice. Below is the statement
 2)  mention the dataframe row and column numbers as mentioned. Below is the modified code

    insert_zero <- function(smpl_vec){
               my_df[2,smpl_vec] <<- 0

            }

          my_df = data.frame('col_1'= c(1,2,3), 'col_2'= c(2,3,4))
          sapply(1:ncol(my_df), function(smpl_vec) insert_zero(smpl_vec))
```